# Java Daemon Threads closed abruptly in WEBLOGIC server

Tags: java, multithreading

We have daemon threads in our J2EE web application which will serve the data from inbound seed files to the application. 
There are multiple daemons for multiple business activities which will feed the Database of the application invoking in a timely manner.
Suppose one thread for Material definition(Item) creation and one thread for Material(Lot) creation in Data Base.

The abstract Thread run method code is as below

```
1.  while(true)
2.  {
3.    
4.    if(business flag unchecked)  break;
5.
6.    Thread.sleep(xxx) for certain time.
7.
8.    Perform the Business Job 
9.
10.   Insert 'I completed Job at xxx for business xx' to DB.
11.
12.  }
```

Recently in one of our clients place we observed that there was no Database insertions of Step 10 of above code for any business activity Thread after a specific time.
Observed step 10 insertions after WEBLOGIC server is restarted only.

It is ensured by Database journal verification that business flag referred in step 4 in above code is not unchecked which is the only the condition to exit the daemon.

Weblogic server logs registered multiple messages like below at that time from where the threads not invoked and no other exceptions recorded

```
####<Jun 14, 2017 9:15:09 PM CDT> <Info> <WorkManager> <ua00629p> <SomeApp> <ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> 

<1497492909991> <BEA-002939> <The maximum thread constraint weblogic.unicast.DispatchWorkManager has been reached 5 times for the last 200 seconds.>
```

Is it because of any Memory or Process contention that JVM will kill/close the daemon threads or anything else expected?

Is there any way to code sending mail which alerts the users that WEBLOGIC or JVM killed/closed the daemon thread, so that workarounds can be done immediately?

Comment: Hi, could you provide more information about how are you implementing those daemon threads in weblogic, i mean using j2ee api, normal threads or what

Comment: What part of 'The maximum thread constraint `weblogic.unicast.DispatchWorkManager` has been reached 5 times for the last 200 seconds' don't you understand? And do you really not sleep if there is nothing to do, and sleep if there *is* something to do?